# Choosing VSTS Kanban column when creating an EPIC using the VSTS REST API

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops, kanban

I am creating a VSTS Kanban Epic using the REST API. This creates an Epic in the first column of the Kanban.

I want to be able to choose which column it goes into, and also as a second operation be able to move it from column to column using the REST API.

Looking at the list of fields available there is a field 'System.BoardColumn' - is this the correct field to modify to alter the Epic's column?

Thanks

Comment: How did you create "Kanban Epic" or which documents did you referred?

Comment: Using the VSTS REST api, e.g. https://xxx.visualstudio.com/SAFe/_apis/wit/workitems/$Epic?api-version=2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the **`System.State`** field value (`New`, `In process` and `Done`) in REST API, then it will go the related column. Since New is the default value for `System.State` field, it will create in first column if you are not specify the value for `System.State`.

#### Create Epic in second column

To create an Epic shows in second column (`In process`) of Epics board, you can use [create a work item REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item). Such as below example (create Epic `epic3`):

```
PATCH https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Git2/_apis/wit/workitems/$Epic?api-version=1.0
```

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "epic3"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "value": "In Progress"
    }
]
```

Then the `epic3` will show in second column:

[image]

#### Update an existing Epic from a column to another column

You just need to `replace` the value for `System.State` field by [update a field REST API.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-a-field)
Such as above example, to move `e1` (id=53) from first (`New`) column to second (`IN process`) column:

```
PATCH https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/53?api-version=1.0
```

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "value": "In Progress"
    }
]
```

Then the work item e1 will show in the second column:

[image]

Comment: I'm finding you can't directly say which column you want the work item to move to but by changing the state, it will move to a related column. I guess this depends what columns you have configured for the board and what states. But this got me on the right track.

Comment: I tried setting the boardcolumn directly but this is currently readonly and I get an error:

[
{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.BoardColumn","value":"Analyse"}
]

{
    "$id": "1",
    "customProperties": {
        "ReferenceName": null
    },
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF401326: Invalid field status 'ReadOnly' for field 'System.BoardColumn'.",
    "typeName": ... 
}

Comment: The error is caused by the field `System.BoardColumn` actually not exist. You should specify the value for the field which exist.